# how can I get to chrome preference arguments document like profile.content_settings.exceptions.plugins

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, flash, webdriver

While crawling with selenium in a python environment, I had to use flash in the chrome webdriver.

I tried to find a setting that would allow Flash.

The two links below are the information I found.

- https://www.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3#PluginsAllowedForUrls
- https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/

After all, I did not find a clear answer, I found the question on the stack overflow and solved it.

The contents are as follows.
https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/30312/enable-flash-player-on-chrome-62-while-running-selenium-test

```
 ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
prefs.put("profile.default_content_setting_values.plugins", 1);
prefs.put("profile.content_settings.plugin_whitelist.adobe-flash-player", 1);
prefs.put("profile.content_settings.exceptions.plugins.*,*.per_resource.adobe-flash-player", 1);
// Enable Flash for this site
prefs.put("PluginsAllowedForUrls", "https://arlo.netgear.com");
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
```

My question is this.

**1) Where can I find information like**

- profile.default_content_setting_values.plugins
- profile.content_settings.plugin_whitelist.adobe-flash-player
- rofile.content_settings.exceptions.plugins.*,*.per_resource.adobe-flash-player

**2) How can I confirm that it is official information?**

If you have any other way to find this information, please let us know about your keywords.

---

Written by translator, sentences can be awkward. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

1. These are keys in your chrome profile. For example if you were to to open it you can go to profile.content_settings.exceptions.plugins. https://sessionbuddy.com/chrome-profile-location/
2. https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSettings